# How to get logged in user's AD group and OfficeLocation in Blazor Server app using Microsoft Identity Platform?

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-graph-api, claims-based-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a .NET6 Blazor Server app configured to use Microsoft Identity Platform / Azure AD with the simple authentication setup from project creation and uses the standard LoginDisplay.razor component.

I am using a base class for my pages to get the username which works fine:

```
public class PageBase : ComponentBase
{
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState>? AuthenticationState { get; set; }

private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal?> GetUser()
{
    if (AuthenticationState != null)
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationState;
        return authState?.User;
    }
    return null;
}

public async Task<string?> GetUsername()
{
    var user = await GetUser();
    return user?.Identity?.Name;
}
```

I am looking to extend base class this to pull back the users OfficeLocation and AD Group(s) in a new object/method. How can I get these properties back from the Authentication State?

When I watch the ClaimsPrincipal I only get a limited number of fields back:

[image]

I have been looking at using Graph API and this can get the values back I require, but just wondering if this is the best approach.

If you can point me in the right direction on how I can get what I need from Azure AD without Graph API, or indeed if Graph API is the only way I will pursue that approach.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: The claims that are returned are provided by the Identity Platform.  Check the Microsoft Identity Platform / Azure AD configuration as outlined by @Varin.  If you can only do what you need!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add optional claim in Azure Portal:

YourApp => Token Configuration => Add optional claim => Choose ID as type => look for `officeLocation` (or `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` ? ) and check box next to it, and Add.

Then you can use something like this:

```
public async Task<string?> GetOfficeLocation()
{
    var user = await GetUser();
    return user?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "officeLocation")?.Value;
}
```

Thing is, recommended approach is using Graph API. This is because you could reach cookie limits when adding more and more stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks Varin, I will pass this onto DevOps for adding the claims and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: This was it for me @RobC - exposing the necessary claims in the app registration token config in MS Entra (formerly AAD), exposes the user groups to HttpContext.User.Identity.Claims

Answer (score 0):

The DevOps team couldn't find any location fields in optional claims, I checked documentation and it is a very limited in terms of what it exposes on the users account:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Looks like Graph API is the way to go, Thanks anyway guys.